# Running a multithreaded programs using multiple host

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, distributed-computing

I have a program which spins up thousands of threads. I am currently using one host for all the threads which takes a lot of time. If I want to use multiple hosts (say 10 hosts, each running 100 different threads), how should I proceed ?

Comment: What are you doing with all of those threads, exactly?

Comment: I think the question is too broad.
Have you thought about some ideas? Can you provide some more details on the nature of the work you're doing.

Comment: If you have to do computing on such a scale you start looking into technology build for such requirements : like Hadoop, spark / storm... But obviously your question is way too broad!

Comment: Since you tagged question `distributed-computing`, you already seem to know that what you're asking is about **Distributed Computing**, so how about you do some **research** and learn about it?

Answer (score 0):

Having thousands of threads on a single JVM sounds like a bad idea - you may spend most time context-switching instead of doing the actual work.

To split your work across multiple host, you cannot use threads managed by a single JVM. You'll need to have each host exposing an API that can receive part of work and return the result of the work done.

One approach would be to use Java [RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/) (remote method invocation) to complete this task, but really, your question lacks so many details important for the decision of what architecture to choose.

Answer (score 0):

```
Creating 1000 threads in on JVM is very bad design and need to minimise count.
High thread count will not give you multi-threading benefit as context switching will be very frequent and will hit performance.
If you are thinking of dividing in multiple hosts then you need parallel processing system like Hadoop /Spark. 
They internally handles task allocation as well as central system for syncing all hosts on which threads/tasks are running.
```